# How to resolve allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' Error in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I am trying to publish an ASP.NET web forms website to MS Azure through Visual Studio.

However, when I go to my Web.Config file, an error appears under *"targetFramework"* below.

The error message is:

> It is an error to use a section registered as
>   allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level. This
>   error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an
>   application in IIS.

I have tried to rebuild the solution but when I try, the error still appears.

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this?

Here is where the error is appearing in the `<system.web>` of my Web.Config below:

```
 <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with VS2015. I have tried all kind of solutions that did not work out for me. Clean the Project, create a Virtual Directory in IIS, clean in Debug-configuraton, delete the obj-folder, clean in Release-configuration, etc.

The cause of this error in my case was that I have set the publish method to File System and the Target Location was set as a nested subfolder of the project-folder. In this case the web.config is duplicated (one in the project-folder and one in the sub-folder).

Conclusion: make sure that the web.config is not duplicated via a backup-folder or release-directory of your project-folder.